# Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

i've got a problem with my wordpress+plugin website, wp debug show me this:

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
>   in /home/effdbsmi/public_html/new/erotika/wp-content/plugins/sofa-front-post/sofa-front-post.php on
>   line 236
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)
>   in /home/effdbsmi/public_html/new/erotika/wp-content/plugins/sofa-front-post/sofa-front-post.php on
>   line 236
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in /home/effdbsmi/public_html/new/erotika/wp-content/plugins/sofa-front-post/sofa-front-post.php on
>   line 236
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given
>   in /home/effdbsmi/public_html/new/erotika/wp-content/plugins/sofa-front-post/sofa-front-post.php on
>   line 236
>
> at the 236 line of sofa-front-post.php there is that code (here in in
>   line 4):

```js
 function sfp_create_database_table() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'sfp_payments';
   if( mysql_num_rows( mysql_query( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table . "'" ) ) == 1) return;
   $run_sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table . " (
       id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       post_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       user_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       pub_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'free',
       paypal_bulk LONGTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       UNIQUE KEY id (id)
       );";
  
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   dbDelta( $run_sql );
  }
```

What can I do ?? Thank you, guys..

Comment: Update your php, mysql version and also update your plugin

Comment: Use `mysqli` (look into the reference, it works slightly different to mysql)

Comment: The basic problem here is, I think, that WordPress provides its own way for plugins to connect to the database and you are trying to bypass it. I don't know WordPress well enough to explain how to fix it. Start by reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Create_Database_Tables — I don't think you should be going anywhere near `mysql_` functions directly (nor, for that matter `mysqli_` or `PDO` since WordPress abstracts them).

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is very clear to tell us "The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead ..."

So we need to use mysqli_query() instead of mysql_query(), in Wordpress, in your case, the code should change as following:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if( mysqli_num_rows( mysqli_query( $connection, "SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table . "'" ) ) == 1) return;
....
```

Answer (score -1):

You can doing the test for the existence of the table like this :

```
if( $wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$table."'") == $table) return;
```

Answer (score -6):

You can ignore all of those messages except this one:

"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

It's saying you provided no password for MySQL.  Provide a password and you will be good to go.

"The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed" - Just ignore it unless you want to re-engineer your code (Which is a good idea but not essential).

"A link to the server could not be established" - This is just a result of the password error above

"mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" - This is just a result of the password error too.

Comment: He can, but shouldn't

Comment: "Provide a password" — That isn't as simple as you suggest since the password comes from a config file.

Comment: bad advice : there is a reason why these functions will be deprecated. I dont think OP would fancy some nasty sql injections in the general area of `sfp_payments` (among others).